# Locust/Selenium - Running in headless mode the execution stops after user logs in

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, locust

I'm running a configuration with Locust | realbrowserlocusts and with a certain application the execution just stops after the assigned user process logs into the application in headlessmode. In browsermode the execution keeps going with no issues. The full logging in the terminal window shows the user logs in - in it's correct state.

I don't have the same issue with a different application, same approach so I'm really puzzled over it.
My first thought was that a redirect was occurring and possibly the webdriver was loosing context with the window so I added some code: self.client.switch_to.default_content() which didn't make any difference. I took out a wait.until function call on the next line and placed a wait timer and that didn't make any difference either as the next object call failed to execute.

self.client.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "wwe-workspace-tab-0")))

Here's my current chrome options.
def **init**(self):
super(HeadlessChromeLocust, self).**init**()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--disable-crash-reporter")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--disable-in-process-stack-traces")
options.add_argument("--disable-logging")
# options.add_argument("--log-level=4")
options.add_argument("--output=/dev/null")
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--auth-server-whitelist=*')

```
from realbrowserlocusts import HeadlessChromeLocust
from realbrowserlocusts import ChromeLocust
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
# from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from locust import TaskSet, task
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotInteractableException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from datetime import datetime

import win32com.client

import time
import calendar
import logging, sys
import csv

usernames = [
    "LoadTest_Agent001",
    "LoadTest_Agent002",
    "LoadTest_Agent003",
    "LoadTest_Agent004",
    "LoadTest_Agent005",
    "LoadTest_Agent006",
    "LoadTest_Agent007",
    "LoadTest_Agent010",
    "LoadTest_Agent009",
    "LoadTest_Agent008"
]

SHORT_SLEEP = 5
MEDIUM_SLEEP = 10
LONG_SLEEP = 20


class Omnichat(TaskSet):

    # self.message = ''

def on_start(self):
    self.message = ''
    if len(usernames) > 0:
        self.username = usernames.pop()
        print(self.username)

    self.client.delete_all_cookies()



def open_agent_homepage(self):

    print("SitePage")
    # Load the site page
    self.client.get("https://myhost/ui/ad/v1/index.html")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("SitePage check for element on site page")
    self.client.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "Layer_2")), "Site page timeout")

def open_agent_login(self):
    self.client.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "wweLoginUserNameField")), "Login Field")
    # Enter username
    self.client.find_element_by_id("wweLoginUserNameField").click()
    self.client.find_element_by_id("wweLoginUserNameField").clear()
    self.client.find_element_by_id("wweLoginUserNameField").send_keys(self.username)
    self.client.find_element_by_id("wweLoginSignInButton").click()
    print("looking for My workspace after login")
    # self.client.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='wwe-workspace-tab-0']/span")))
    
    #  FAILS TO MOVE PAST THIS POINT
    self.client.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "wwe-workspace-tab-0")))
    print("Found the workspace text")
    # self.client.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='wwe-workspace-tab-0']/span")))
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not simulate this on my machine, but just a suggestion quick reading through articles I learned that default window size for chrome in headless mode could be too small 800x600 (not fully maximized)

You can try amending code to launch headless chrome in your chrome options.

**Reference:**

- https://forum.katalon.com/t/headless-element-not-visible/7217/3
- https://itnext.io/how-to-run-a-headless-chrome-browser-in-selenium-webdriver-c5521bc12bf0